# EF core how to prevent duplicated values for a set of rows

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm looking for a way to prevent duplicated entries. This is my scenario:

I have a model named Person

```cs
    public class Person 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Citizenship { get; set; }
    }
```

If I insert the first record with name John, surname Doe and citizenship American. Subsequently, if I insert another record as name John, surname Doe and citizenship French, I want EF Core to pick that up as a duplicate because we already have John Doe as an existing record.

Comment: What kind of response do you want from EF Core? An exception thrown at an attempt to insert a duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a unique index for your model in the `OnModelCreating` override on your `DbContext`.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
        .HasIndex(p => new { p.Name, p.Surname })
        .IsUnique();
}
```

Or as an attribute on your Person class:

```
[Index(nameof(Name), nameof(Surname), IsUnique=true)]
public class Person
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Surname { get; set; }
   public string Citizenship { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Would a composite key work for this situation?

Comment: @Lee the person has an id, so I guess that's the key.

Answer (score 3):

[image: evidence that it works]add this to the OnModelCreating

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
              .HasIndex(e => new { e.Name, e.Surname })
              .IsUnique();
```

Please change the property type to string thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use this extention for this:

```
public static class LinqExtention
    {
        public static IEnumerable<T> DistinctBy<T, TKey>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, TKey> property)
        {
            return items.GroupBy(property).Select(x => x.First());
        }
    }
```

usage:

```
var newList= db.persons.DistinctBy(x=>new {x.Name,x.Surname }).ToList();
```